# CSV Import into QGIS seems to be imported as attribute table, should be point coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, import

I'm trying to import a .csv table to QGIS with temperature-data from  different German districts. I have all the districts with lat/lon coordinates in my list, but the CSV seems to be imported as an attribute-table-layer. Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They aren't GMS (DMS)

Answer (score 2):

As @IanTurton notes, your coordinates aren't DMS (Degrees Minutes Seconds). They are DD (Decimal Degrees) so just untick the DMS coordinates (GMS-Koordinaten) checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try unticking GMS-Koordinaten, i believe this is DMS Coordinates, and your lat longs are in Decimal.